# UICloudSharingController does not show "Add People" with existing share in iOS 15.x but does in iOS 14.x

Tags: cloudkit, ios15, cloudkit-sharing

Running iOS 14.x or lower the UICloudSharingController shows Add People as the last line of the 1st section of the People sheet.

As of iOS 15.x including the new 15.2 beta the row containing Add People is not present.

Anyone know of a work around until Apple fixes this?  Apple 1st party Apps like notes do not appear to be affected by this issue, but all my Apps that share using the UICloudSharingController exhibit this issue even those not recompiled under xcode 13.x

[image]

[image]

Comment: This appears to be Fixed by Apple in iOS 15.2 beta 2 !